# Random numbers are changed when orientation is changed

Tags: android

Hi I am generating the random numbers and do some functionality with that .but when i change the otientation new random numbers are coming.But I want portrait random nimbers.For this give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because each time you change the handset orientation, the whole activity is destroyed and rebuilt, so the numbers are being generated again. There are many ways to save the state of your app, so that it does not generate the random numbers more than once. You could take a look at [#151777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)